# Can I install a Surface Pro 4 from a Windows 10 image on USB?

Tags: windows-10, installation, microsoft-surface

My surface pro 10 from MS needs to be "reinstalled/reset/formatted"

However, I don't have a large enough USB drive to download MS recovery stuff (needs to be 16GB). I do have a USB drive with Windows 10 on it.

Can I just boot from that windows 10 usb drive, format `C:` and install Windows 10, like I do on my normal workstation computer? Or is the Surface Pro 4 special and must it be reset/formatted with the recovery image from Microsoft?

If you ask: *Why do I need to reset/format my surface?* Well, it won't start. Windows just loads and loads and loads. A whole night of loading and nothing.

Restarted (yes shut down with 30 sec press on power button) several times. Still get stuck on the loading screen.

Can not figure out how to get it back up and running without formatting and do a clean install of everything.

Comment: What is "MS recovery stuff"? Why do you think you need it and your Windows 10 won't be enough? Why haven't you tried it yet, it seems you can't lose too much.

Comment: Stuff = this :) https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage . And i am afraid to test to format c: on a surface if it is not working as a "normal" computer... i dont know, thats why i am asking.

Comment: Absolutely;  I just did this recently in December; I suggest using the Surface Pro 4 image provided by Microsoft though;  You still need a larger Flash storage device since you will be installing a 64-bit version of Windows